# How to get the plotly theme as a dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, themes

I would like to have the definition of the `plotly` theme (or any other theme that comes with `plotly` for that reason) as a dictionary, i.e., in this format:

```
ggplot' : {
            'colorscale':'ggplot',
            'linewidth':1.3,
            'linecolor':'pearl',
            'bargap' : .01,
            'layout' : {
                'legend' : {'bgcolor':'white','font':{'color':'grey10'}},
                'paper_bgcolor' : 'white',
                'plot_bgcolor' : 'grey14',
                'yaxis' : {
                    'tickfont' : {'color':'grey10'},
                    'gridcolor' : 'lightivory',
                    'titlefont' : {'color':'grey10'},
                    'zerolinecolor' : 'lightivory',
                    'showgrid' : True
                },
                'xaxis' : {
                    'tickfont' : {'color':'grey10'},
                    'gridcolor' : 'lightivory',
                    'titlefont' : {'color':'grey10'},
                    'zerolinecolor' : 'lightivory',
                    'showgrid' : True
                },
                'titlefont' : {'color':'charcoal'}
            },
            'annotations' : {
                'fontcolor' : 'grey10',
                'arrowcolor' : 'grey10'
            }
```

In other words, I would like to know the specs of the theme.

How I can get this information?

Answer (score 0):

You can import plotly.io.  Then you can view your template options and view the dictionary for each. See more about themes in the [plotly docs](https://plotly.com/python/templates/).

```
import plotly.io as pio

#View possible templates
print(pio.templates)

#View dictionary of a specific template
print(pio.templates['plotly_white'])
```

Output:

```
Templates configuration
-----------------------
    Default template: 'plotly'
    Available templates:
        ['ggplot2', 'seaborn', 'simple_white', 'plotly',
         'plotly_white', 'plotly_dark', 'presentation', 'xgridoff',
         'ygridoff', 'gridon', 'none']

layout.Template({
    'data': {'bar': [{'error_x': {'color': '#2a3f5f'},
                      'error_y': {'color': '#2a3f5f'},
                      'marker': {'line': {'color': 'white', 'width': 0.5},
                                 'pattern': {'fillmode': 'overlay', 'size': 10, 'solidity': 0.2}},
                      'type': 'bar'}],
             'barpolar': [{'marker': {'line': {'color': 'white', 'width': 0.5},
                                      'pattern': {'fillmode': 'overlay', 'size': 10, 'solidity': 0.2}},
                           'type': 'barpolar'}],
             'carpet': [{'aaxis': {'endlinecolor': '#2a3f5f',
                                   'gridcolor': '#C8D4E3',
                                   'linecolor': '#C8D4E3',
                                   'minorgridcolor': '#C8D4E3',
                                   'startlinecolor': '#2a3f5f'},
                         'baxis': {'endlinecolor': '#2a3f5f',
                                   'gridcolor': '#C8D4E3',
                                   'linecolor': '#C8D4E3',
                                   'minorgridcolor': '#C8D4E3',
                                   'startlinecolor': '#2a3f5f'},
                         'type': 'carpet'}],
             'choropleth': [{'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}, 'type': 'choropleth'}],
             'contour': [{'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''},
                          'colorscale': [[0.0, '#0d0887'], [0.1111111111111111,
                                         '#46039f'], [0.2222222222222222,
                                         '#7201a8'], [0.3333333333333333,
                                         '#9c179e'], [0.4444444444444444,
                                         '#bd3786'], [0.5555555555555556,
                                         '#d8576b'], [0.6666666666666666,
                                         '#ed7953'], [0.7777777777777778,
                                         '#fb9f3a'], [0.8888888888888888,
                                         '#fdca26'], [1.0, '#f0f921']],
                          'type': 'contour'}],
             'contourcarpet': [{'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}, 'type': 'contourcarpet'}],
             'heatmap': [{'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''},
                          'colorscale': [[0.0, '#0d0887'], [0.1111111111111111,
                                         '#46039f'], [0.2222222222222222,
                                         '#7201a8'], [0.3333333333333333,
                                         '#9c179e'], [0.4444444444444444,
                                         '#bd3786'], [0.5555555555555556,
                                         '#d8576b'], [0.6666666666666666,
                                         '#ed7953'], [0.7777777777777778,
                                         '#fb9f3a'], [0.8888888888888888,
                                         '#fdca26'], [1.0, '#f0f921']],
                          'type': 'heatmap'}],
             'heatmapgl': [{'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''},
                            'colorscale': [[0.0, '#0d0887'], [0.1111111111111111,
                                           '#46039f'], [0.2222222222222222,
                                           '#7201a8'], [0.3333333333333333,
                                           '#9c179e'], [0.4444444444444444,
                                           '#bd3786'], [0.5555555555555556,
                                           '#d8576b'], [0.6666666666666666,
                                           '#ed7953'], [0.7777777777777778,
                                           '#fb9f3a'], [0.8888888888888888,
                                           '#fdca26'], [1.0, '#f0f921']],
                            'type': 'heatmapgl'}],
             'histogram': [{'marker': {'pattern': {'fillmode': 'overlay', 'size': 10, 'solidity': 0.2}},
                            'type': 'histogram'}],
             'histogram2d': [{'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''},
                              'colorscale': [[0.0, '#0d0887'],
                                             [0.1111111111111111, '#46039f'],
                                             [0.2222222222222222, '#7201a8'],
                                             [0.3333333333333333, '#9c179e'],
                                             [0.4444444444444444, '#bd3786'],
                                             [0.5555555555555556, '#d8576b'],
                                             [0.6666666666666666, '#ed7953'],
                                             [0.7777777777777778, '#fb9f3a'],
                                             [0.8888888888888888, '#fdca26'], [1.0,
                                             '#f0f921']],
                              'type': 'histogram2d'}],
             'histogram2dcontour': [{'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''},
                                     'colorscale': [[0.0, '#0d0887'],
                                                    [0.1111111111111111,
                                                    '#46039f'],
                                                    [0.2222222222222222,
                                                    '#7201a8'],
                                                    [0.3333333333333333,
                                                    '#9c179e'],
                                                    [0.4444444444444444,
                                                    '#bd3786'],
                                                    [0.5555555555555556,
                                                    '#d8576b'],
                                                    [0.6666666666666666,
                                                    '#ed7953'],
                                                    [0.7777777777777778,
                                                    '#fb9f3a'],
                                                    [0.8888888888888888,
                                                    '#fdca26'], [1.0, '#f0f921']],
                                     'type': 'histogram2dcontour'}],
             'mesh3d': [{'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}, 'type': 'mesh3d'}],
             'parcoords': [{'line': {'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}}, 'type': 'parcoords'}],
             'pie': [{'automargin': True, 'type': 'pie'}],
             'scatter': [{'fillpattern': {'fillmode': 'overlay', 'size': 10, 'solidity': 0.2}, 'type': 'scatter'}],
             'scatter3d': [{'line': {'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}},
                            'marker': {'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}},
                            'type': 'scatter3d'}],
             'scattercarpet': [{'marker': {'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}}, 'type': 'scattercarpet'}],
             'scattergeo': [{'marker': {'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}}, 'type': 'scattergeo'}],
             'scattergl': [{'marker': {'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}}, 'type': 'scattergl'}],
             'scattermapbox': [{'marker': {'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}}, 'type': 'scattermapbox'}],
             'scatterpolar': [{'marker': {'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}}, 'type': 'scatterpolar'}],
             'scatterpolargl': [{'marker': {'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}}, 'type': 'scatterpolargl'}],
             'scatterternary': [{'marker': {'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}}, 'type': 'scatterternary'}],
             'surface': [{'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''},
                          'colorscale': [[0.0, '#0d0887'], [0.1111111111111111,
                                         '#46039f'], [0.2222222222222222,
                                         '#7201a8'], [0.3333333333333333,
                                         '#9c179e'], [0.4444444444444444,
                                         '#bd3786'], [0.5555555555555556,
                                         '#d8576b'], [0.6666666666666666,
                                         '#ed7953'], [0.7777777777777778,
                                         '#fb9f3a'], [0.8888888888888888,
                                         '#fdca26'], [1.0, '#f0f921']],
                          'type': 'surface'}],
             'table': [{'cells': {'fill': {'color': '#EBF0F8'}, 'line': {'color': 'white'}},
                        'header': {'fill': {'color': '#C8D4E3'}, 'line': {'color': 'white'}},
                        'type': 'table'}]},
    'layout': {'annotationdefaults': {'arrowcolor': '#2a3f5f', 'arrowhead': 0, 'arrowwidth': 1},
               'autotypenumbers': 'strict',
               'coloraxis': {'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}},
               'colorscale': {'diverging': [[0, '#8e0152'], [0.1, '#c51b7d'],
                                            [0.2, '#de77ae'], [0.3, '#f1b6da'],
                                            [0.4, '#fde0ef'], [0.5, '#f7f7f7'],
                                            [0.6, '#e6f5d0'], [0.7, '#b8e186'],
                                            [0.8, '#7fbc41'], [0.9, '#4d9221'], [1,
                                            '#276419']],
                              'sequential': [[0.0, '#0d0887'],
                                             [0.1111111111111111, '#46039f'],
                                             [0.2222222222222222, '#7201a8'],
                                             [0.3333333333333333, '#9c179e'],
                                             [0.4444444444444444, '#bd3786'],
                                             [0.5555555555555556, '#d8576b'],
                                             [0.6666666666666666, '#ed7953'],
                                             [0.7777777777777778, '#fb9f3a'],
                                             [0.8888888888888888, '#fdca26'], [1.0,
                                             '#f0f921']],
                              'sequentialminus': [[0.0, '#0d0887'],
                                                  [0.1111111111111111, '#46039f'],
                                                  [0.2222222222222222, '#7201a8'],
                                                  [0.3333333333333333, '#9c179e'],
                                                  [0.4444444444444444, '#bd3786'],
                                                  [0.5555555555555556, '#d8576b'],
                                                  [0.6666666666666666, '#ed7953'],
                                                  [0.7777777777777778, '#fb9f3a'],
                                                  [0.8888888888888888, '#fdca26'],
                                                  [1.0, '#f0f921']]},
               'colorway': [#636efa, #EF553B, #00cc96, #ab63fa, #FFA15A, #19d3f3,
                            #FF6692, #B6E880, #FF97FF, #FECB52],
               'font': {'color': '#2a3f5f'},
               'geo': {'bgcolor': 'white',
                       'lakecolor': 'white',
                       'landcolor': 'white',
                       'showlakes': True,
                       'showland': True,
                       'subunitcolor': '#C8D4E3'},
               'hoverlabel': {'align': 'left'},
               'hovermode': 'closest',
               'mapbox': {'style': 'light'},
               'paper_bgcolor': 'white',
               'plot_bgcolor': 'white',
               'polar': {'angularaxis': {'gridcolor': '#EBF0F8', 'linecolor': '#EBF0F8', 'ticks': ''},
                         'bgcolor': 'white',
                         'radialaxis': {'gridcolor': '#EBF0F8', 'linecolor': '#EBF0F8', 'ticks': ''}},
               'scene': {'xaxis': {'backgroundcolor': 'white',
                                   'gridcolor': '#DFE8F3',
                                   'gridwidth': 2,
                                   'linecolor': '#EBF0F8',
                                   'showbackground': True,
                                   'ticks': '',
                                   'zerolinecolor': '#EBF0F8'},
                         'yaxis': {'backgroundcolor': 'white',
                                   'gridcolor': '#DFE8F3',
                                   'gridwidth': 2,
                                   'linecolor': '#EBF0F8',
                                   'showbackground': True,
                                   'ticks': '',
                                   'zerolinecolor': '#EBF0F8'},
                         'zaxis': {'backgroundcolor': 'white',
                                   'gridcolor': '#DFE8F3',
                                   'gridwidth': 2,
                                   'linecolor': '#EBF0F8',
                                   'showbackground': True,
                                   'ticks': '',
                                   'zerolinecolor': '#EBF0F8'}},
               'shapedefaults': {'line': {'color': '#2a3f5f'}},
               'ternary': {'aaxis': {'gridcolor': '#DFE8F3', 'linecolor': '#A2B1C6', 'ticks': ''},
                           'baxis': {'gridcolor': '#DFE8F3', 'linecolor': '#A2B1C6', 'ticks': ''},
                           'bgcolor': 'white',
                           'caxis': {'gridcolor': '#DFE8F3', 'linecolor': '#A2B1C6', 'ticks': ''}},
               'title': {'x': 0.05},
               'xaxis': {'automargin': True,
                         'gridcolor': '#EBF0F8',
                         'linecolor': '#EBF0F8',
                         'ticks': '',
                         'title': {'standoff': 15},
                         'zerolinecolor': '#EBF0F8',
                         'zerolinewidth': 2},
               'yaxis': {'automargin': True,
                         'gridcolor': '#EBF0F8',
                         'linecolor': '#EBF0F8',
                         'ticks': '',
                         'title': {'standoff': 15},
                         'zerolinecolor': '#EBF0F8',
                         'zerolinewidth': 2}}
})
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76336543/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).